# Duplicate Records in a SQL Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables in a SQL Server database (2008 R2): Bidders, Sales, and Transactions.

I have six bidders who have a sale or sales and there are a total of six sales.  In the Transaction table are a total of six records.  The data is as follows:

Bidder Table Data:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| Bidder ID |       Bidder Name       |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|       101 | Tom & Joan Bergland     |
|       103 | Jack & Sally Cook       |
|       106 | Steve & Jan Cross       |
|       109 | Cynthia Davis           |
|       122 | Arnold & Peggy Jensen   |
|       126 | Wayne & Connie Lindell  |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Sales Table Data:

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| Sales Counter | BidderNumber | AmountSpent | Quantity   |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|             1 |          101 | 2600.00     |        1   |
|             2 |          106 | 90.00       |        1   |
|             3 |          122 | 65.00       |        1   |
|             4 |          103 | 353.00      |        2   |
|             5 |          126 | 2500.00     |        1   |
|             6 |          109 | 315.00      |        3   |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

Transaction Table Data:

```
+--------------+------------+------------------+
| BidderNumber | AmountPaid | SalesCounter     |
+--------------+------------+------------------+
|          101 | 2600.00    |              1   |
|          103 | 500.00     |              4   |
|          103 | 206.00     |              4   |
|          122 | 65.00      |              3   |
|          126 | 1500.00    |              5   |
|          126 | 1000.00    |              5   |
+--------------+------------+------------------+
```

Here is the SQL code I am using to get the data I am looking for:

```
Select s.[BidderNumber] as 'Bid #',
   ltrim(rtrim(b.bidderName)) as 'Name',
    isnull(sum(s.saleprice * Quantity),0) as 'Spent', 
   isnull(sum(t.Amount),0) as 'Paid', 
   case 
        when sum(t.Amount) is null then sum(s.saleprice * Quantity) 
        else
            case when (sum(t.Amount) > sum(s.saleprice * Quantity)) then (sum(t.Amount) - sum(s.saleprice * Quantity)) 
                 else (sum(s.saleprice * Quantity) - sum(t.amount ))
                 end
        end as 'Outstanding', b.cconfile, t.Notes --, s.biddernumber 
Into #Temp1
from sales s inner join Bidders b on s.BidderNumber = b.BidderNumber
             left  join transactions t on s.SaleCounter = t.SalesCounter  

group by s.BidderNumber, b.bidderName,b.CCOnFile, t.Notes  
order by s.Biddernumber, b.biddername, b.cconfile, t.Notes

  Select [Bid #], Name, Spent as 'Total Purchases', Paid as 'Current Payments', 
       case
            when CCOnFile = 1 then Sum(Outstanding)
           else
                case 
                        when CCOnFile = 0 then 0
                    end
            end as 'Amount To Charge Credit Card',
        case
            when CCOnFile = 0 then sum(Outstanding)
            ELSE
                case
                    when CCOnfile = 1 then 0
                    end
            end as 'Outstanding Balance',
            isnull(Notes,' ')as 'Notes'             
from #Temp1 
group by [Bid #], name, spent, paid,CCOnFile,Notes
order by [Bid #], Name, spent, paid, CCOnFile,Notes


drop table #temp1
```

Here are the results I am getting back:

Bid #   Name    Total Purchases Current Payments Amount To Charge Credit Card   Outstanding Balance  Notes
101   Tom & Joan Bergland     2600.00     2600.00     0.00    0.00
103   Jack & Sally Cook   1412.00     706.00      0.00    706.00
106   Steve & Jan Cross   90.00    0.00   0.00    90.00
109   Cynthia Davis 945.00    0.00     0.00   945.00
122   Arnold & Peggy Jensen   65.00    65.00  0.00    0.00
126   Wayne & Connie Lindell  5000.00  2500.00  0.00    2500.00

My question is simply this: why are the total purchases being doubled?  And the doubled totals are ONLY happening when there are two records in the transaction table (see ids number 103 and 126.

Granted, SQL is not my strongest skill, but I think I have this coded correctly.  But after 3 days of banging my head, I could really use some advice.

Thanks!!

Comment: what does the 3rd column denote in the Sales table and the Transation table and where is Quantity coming from?

Comment: The 3rd column in the Sales table denotes the amount of the sale.  The 3rd column in the transaction table is the salescounter.  The quantity is coming from the front end application using the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at sale table: **4** 103 353.00 2 
and the transaction table: 103 500.00 **4**
103 206.00 **4**

When you left join sales and transactions, because the key to join have 2 rows in transactions table so the result will be duplicated, see the join result below:
4 103 353.00 2 103 500.00 4
4 103 353.00 2 103 206.00 4

==> Total Purchases = 353 * 2 + 353*2 = 1412.00

In your sql, instead of left join transactions you should move the case to second select statement and move the calculate pad to sub select like this

```
Select s.[BidderNumber] as 'Bid #',
    ltrim(rtrim(b.bidderName)) as 'Name',
    isnull(sum(s.saleprice * Quantity),0) as 'Spent', 
    (select isnull(sum(t.Amount),0) from transactions t
          where t.SalesCounter = s.SaleCounter) as 'Paid', b.cconfile, t.Notes --, s.biddernumber 
Into #Temp1
from sales s inner join Bidders b on s.BidderNumber = b.BidderNumber
group by s.BidderNumber, b.bidderName, b.CCOnFile
order by s.Biddernumber, b.biddername, b.cconfile
```

Comment: I gratefully appreciate the answer!  I'll give this a try here in a a few minutes and let you know how this goes.

Comment: Vu I appreciate it.  That worked for me!  Marked your response as the answer.